# How and where to create icons for iOS?

Tags: nativescript

I've read the docs at [AppIcons for iOS](https://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/creating-launch-screens-ios#customizing-app-icons).

I read "Drag and drop your Assets.xcassets into Xcode (7.1 or newer version)." Not sure what that means exactly. Drop the folder on the Xcode icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dashman yep -exactly! Just drag'n'drop the folder in XCode. However, notice that this won't work directly from VSCode. So these are the actual steps:

- Open in Finder `Assets.xcassets` folder located in ***app/App_Resources/ioS***
- select the folder and drag and drop in Xcode (opened or not)
- the WYSIWIG screen for modifying your icons will load.